# variable in atribute of HTML element by go web server

Tags: html, go

I have Go web server makes request to SQL database and show result in webpage, also there is a selector in the table

[image]

I want to handle the state of the selectors by name. In my go code i prepare the assinment

```
            type Device_view struct {
            Device_number string                // struct to add data from SQL-query to HTML
            Device_name string
            Device_status bool
            }
           
          type Data struct {                             // additional struct for loop 
              Items []Device_view
        }
        
          data := Data{}
          i := 1
          for _, dv := range dev {                          // loop
            view := Device_view{
                Device_number: strconv.Itoa(i),
                Device_name: dv.rele_name,
                Device_status: dv.rele_status,
            }   
                i = i + 1
                data.Items = append(data.Items, view)
          }
          tmpl, _ := template.ParseFiles("./templates/index.html")     // parsing HTML to web page
          tmpl.Execute(response, data)
```

and i don't know how to assign name of the selectors in HTML by code.

```
<table border="1">
    <caption>Device</caption>
    <tr>
     <th>DEVICE</th>
     <th>CURRENT STATE</th>
     <th>NEW STATE</th>
    </tr>
    {{ range .Items}}
    <tr>
     <td>{{ .Device_name}}</td>
     <td>{{ .Device_status}}</td>      
     <td><select name = ???><option>ON</option><option>OFF</option></select></td>
    </tr>
   {{ end}}
   </table>
    <button type="submit">SET DEVICE STATUS</button>
</form>
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```
<td><select name = {{ .Device_number}}><option>ON</option><option>OFF</option></select></td>
```

Comment: Did you try `<select name="{{.Device_number}}">`? And if yes, what was the result? What specific problem did you encounter? Note that `tmpl.Execute` returns an error that you are not checking, if it's non-nil it may provide valuable info as to what is wrong with your template.

Comment: (unrelated) In general you should parse the template only once and reuse the result.

Answer (score 0):

Oh! i'm stupid, thanks for @mkopriva , i have a solution in my question

```
select name = "{{ .Device_number}}"
```

works!